# multiple authors in one line

Tags: titles

I have found a simple article template at: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~yogi/Courses/CS-Scientific-Writing/examples/simple/simple.htm

But I want that the authors appear in the same line and not one below another. I have tried different solutions and no luck at all. The code that I have is the following:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\author{
        Vitaly Surazhsky \\
                Department of Computer Science\\
        Technion---Israel Institute of Technology\\
        Technion City, Haifa 32000, \underline{Israel}
        \texttt{first1.last1@xxxxx.com}
        \and
        Yossi Gil\\
        Department of Computer Science\\
        Technion---Israel Institute of Technology\\
        Technion City, Haifa 32000, \underline{Israel}
}
\title{A Very Simple \LaTeXe{} Template}
\date{\today}
```

I have looked at different examples, but I cannot still get what is wrong.
Any help?

Answer (score 6):

The problem starts with the font size and the lengthy text for each author. Here are some alternatives.
The first one:

```
\title{A Very Simple \LaTeXe{} Template}
\author{Vitaly Surazhsky\thanks{Department of Computer Science,
        Technion---Israel Institute of Technology,
        Technion City, Haifa 32000, \underline{Israel}}        
    \and    
    Yossi Gil\thanks{Department of Computer Science,
        Technion---Israel Institute of Technology,
        Technion City, Haifa 32000, \underline{Israel}}}%

\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is the paper's abstract \ldots
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
This is time for all good men to come to the aid of their party!

\paragraph{Outline}
The remainder of this article is organized as follows.
Section~\ref{previous work} gives account of previous work.
Our new and exciting results are described in Section~\ref{results}.
Finally, Section~\ref{conclusions} gives the conclusions.

\section{Previous work}\label{previous work}
A much longer \LaTeXe{} example was written by Gil~\cite{Gil:02}.

\section{Results}\label{results}
In this section we describe the results.



\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second one I reduced the font size but also modified the margin length:

```
\title{A Very Simple \LaTeXe{} Template}
\author{
    Vitaly Surazhsky \\
    \small{Department of Computer Science}\\
\small{ Technion---Israel Institute of Technology}\\
    \small{Technion City, Haifa 32000, \underline{Israel}}
    \and
    Yossi Gil\\
    \small{Department of Computer Science}\\
\small{ Technion---Israel Institute of Technology}\\
\small{Technion City, Haifa 32000, \underline{Israel}}
}
\date{\today}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{abstract}
        This is the paper's abstract \ldots
    \end{abstract}

    \section{Introduction}
    This is time for all good men to come to the aid of their party!

    \paragraph{Outline}
    The remainder of this article is organized as follows.
    Section~\ref{previous work} gives account of previous work.
    Our new and exciting results are described in Section~\ref{results}.
    Finally, Section~\ref{conclusions} gives the conclusions.

    \section{Previous work}\label{previous work}
    A much longer \LaTeXe{} example was written by Gil~\cite{Gil:02}.

    \section{Results}\label{results}
    In this section we describe the results.

    \section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}
    We worked hard, and achieved very little.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, I personally use the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in}
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\title{A Very Simple \LaTeXe{} Template}
\author{Vitaly Surazhsky}
\author{Yossi Gil}%
\thanks{Vitaly Surazhsky and    Yossi Gil are with Department of Computer Science,Technion---Israel Institute of Technology, Technion City, Haifa 32000, \underline{Israel}}%
\begin{abstract}
This is the paper's abstract \ldots
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is time for all good men to come to the aid of their party!

\paragraph{Outline}
The remainder of this article is organized as follows.
Section~\ref{previous work} gives account of previous work.
Our new and exciting results are described in Section~\ref{results}.
Finally, Section~\ref{conclusions} gives the conclusions.

\section{Previous work}\label{previous work}
A much longer \LaTeXe{} example was written by Gil~\cite{Gil:02}.

\section{Results}\label{results}
In this section we describe the results.

\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}
We worked hard, and achieved very little.



\end{document}
```

[image]