# Two authors in same line (article class)

Tags: titles

I'm trying to put two different authors on the same line in my document. I've tried EVERYTHING but my document typesets them on different lines each.

This is part of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nosectionbib,numberedbib]{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\refname{Reference}}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{fnpct}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Header}
\cfoot{\thepage}



\title{\textsc{Title}}

\author[*]{Name -- No. \and
Name -- No.}

\date{Sept 2018}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1pt}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

This is my result:
[image]

I want both names and No. (numbers) on the same line as to not take too much space.

I'm looking for something like this:
[image]
Or this:
[image]

Comment: You could see this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403335/14423 ... I thinks this post is duplicated

Answer (score 2):

The [`authblk`](https://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package is not so flexible.  Best I could come up with is this, abusing the affiliation field for email addresses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\begin{document}

\title{\textsc{Title}}
\date{Sept 2018}
\author{Name Surname}
\affil{\texttt{emailh@outlook.com}}
\author{Name Surname}
\affil{\texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]