# Format Title Page of Article Class: Three Authors With The Same Affiliation and One Author with Different Affiliation

Tags: symbols, article

I have three authors with the same affiliation for an article. Thus, I want the affiliation of those three authors to appear once with their symbol.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{authblk}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{%
    \normalsize\href{mailto:#1}{#1}\par
}
\title{\textbf{{\Large My Tittle for the Article }}}% to see the effect

\author[$\dagger$]{\textbf{\large Author A}}
\author[$\star$]{\textbf{\large Author B}}
\author[$\dagger$]{\textbf{\large Author C}}
\author[$\dagger$]{\textbf{\large Author D}}

\affil[$\dagger$]{\textbf{\normalsize University of Latex}}
\affil[$\star$]{\textbf{\normalsize University of R \vspace{-10ex}}}
\affil[$\dagger$]{\textbf{\normalsize University of Latex}}
\affil[$\dagger$]{\textbf{\normalsize University of Latex}}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Here is what I have [image: in this output]

I checked [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452166/two-authors-in-same-line-article-class) but that does not answer my question

**What I Want**

I only want the symbol(dagger), Univerity of Latex to appear once and then the second symbol(star) University of R to also appear once as affiliation.

[image: Like this]

Comment: Use only `\affil[$\dagger$]{\textbf{\normalsize University of Latex}}
\affil[$\star$]{\textbf{\normalsize University of R }}`. Remove the last two.

Comment: Problem solved?